Change description missing in git releases triggered by semantic release
I recently implemented semantic-release and versioning plugins in my application to streamline versioning, tagging, and releases. Below is my releaserc.yml configuration:
branches:
  - '+([0-9])?(.{+([0-9]),x}).x'
  - main
  - master
  - name: alpha
    prerelease: true
plugins:
  - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
  - "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
  - - "@semantic-release/exec"
    - prepareCmd: |
        mvn --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=${nextRelease.version} -s settings.xml\
          && npm version ${nextRelease.version} --allow-same-version --force --workspaces\
      publishCmd: |
        mvn --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress -U clean deploy -s settings.xml \
          && mvn --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress release:update-versions -s settings.xml \
          && git ls-files --modified pom.xml **/pom.xml | xargs git add \
          && git commit -m "[skip ci] prepare for next development iteration" \
          && git push
      verifyReleaseCmd: |
        echo ${nextRelease.version} > .VERSION
  - - "@semantic-release/git"
    - assets:
        - "pom.xml"
        - "**/pom.xml"
        - "package.json"
        - "package-lock.json"
        - "js/package.json"
        - "js-internal/package.json"
  - "@semantic-release/github"
analyzeCommits:
  - path: "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
    releaseRules:
      - type: "breaking"
        release: "major"
      - type: "feat"
        release: "minor"
      - type: "update"
        release: "minor"
      - type: "fix"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "docs"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "style"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "refactor"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "perf"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "test"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "chore"
        release: "patch"
      - type: "revert"
        release: "patch"

Although the configuration appears correct, the automatic releases lack release notes or change descriptions. Sample release: Sample git release
I suspect there may be issues with how the releaseRules are applied by the release notes generator. Despite attempts to update the releaserc.yml file, the issue persists. Automated release notes publishing is crucial for the success of our automation efforts. Any assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

I think you are missing the message attribute/property at the @semantic-release/git plugin, I think that message is the one that the tool uses for release notes. In my .releaserc.js I have it like this:
[
'@semantic-release/git',
{
assets: [
"**/pom.xml",
"docs/CHANGELOG.md"
],
message: [
':bookmark: ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]',
'',
'${nextRelease.notes}'
].join('\n')
}
]

Thanks @BugsForBreakfast for highlighting this, it looks like that the missing attribute, i will try adding this!
